# Show image from database as byte[] in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

i get image from client convert it to byte[] and send it to server. And convert byte[] to Base64String and insert into database.

And i do reverse to show image. But i cant see the image. Why???

```
//Convert to byte array
 public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(WriteableBitmap bitmap)

{
            int[] p = bitmap.Pixels;
            int len = p.Length << 2;
            byte[] result = new byte[len];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);
            return result;
}

//Converter
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write((byte[])value, 0, ((byte[])value).Length);
            image.SetSource(stream);


            return image;
        }

//While writing to database
else if (value.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                return "'" + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])value) + "'";
            }

else if ((type == typeof(byte[])))
            {
                return Convert.FromBase64String((string)value);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BinaryReader and solved the problem.

My problem was not reading the image correct. iused BinaryReader to read the image and solved the problem.

```
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileInfo.OpenRead());

                byte[] tempImage = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length];

                reader.Read(tempImage, 0, tempImage.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following code to convert a byte array directly to an image:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(imageData));
newImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

So as long as the conversion to and from the `Base64String` is working this should be all you need.

As an aside, you don't need to convert to a `Base64String` to store in the database. You just need to set the column type to `image` (assuming you are using MS SQL Server)

Comment: Hi Chris. I use MS-SQL but i use metadata mapping via reflection and query object. And with this domain model i can't add an image data as image. And i strill couldn't make things work.

Comment: @turgut - I think you need to break the problem down. Is it the conversion of image to string that's failing? Or perhaps the storage of the string in the database? Verify the data at each step. Do a conversion from byte[] -> string -> byte[] and check that the result is identical to the input.

Comment: Suprisingly data before convertion and after convertion matches.

Comment: @turgut - in that case I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Base64StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            if (!(value is string)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String((string)value)));
            return bitmapImage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```